# file upload validation in kohana 3.1 not working

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I am stuck with file upload validation in Kohana 3.1. Though the `Upload::not_empty` function returning `false`. I am still getting `true` from `check()` function.

Here is my code

```
$validator = Validation::factory($this->request->post())
        ->rule('name', 'Upload::not_empty', array(':files'))
        ->bind(':files',$_FILES['name']);

var_dump($validator->check());
```

Above the `name` is the **name** of the file field.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by combining `$_POST` and `$_FILES` as suggested by awellis in [this](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/7504/combining-_post-and-_files-validation/p1) thread.

Basically the value of field `name` was not passed in `Validation::factory` so the below code in `Kohana_Validation`'s `check()` function was not returning the error.

```
// Ignore return values from rules when the field is empty
if ( ! in_array($rule, $this->_empty_rules) AND ! Valid::not_empty($value))
    continue;
```